# Lexicographical sorting of matrix

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I'm required to sort the matrix(each row is a feature vector) in lexicographical order.

```
test_mat = [10 40 30 -1 ; 43 78 -5 1; 87 54 -4 -2];
```

But after looking at several posts, there are:

```
sortrows(test_mat)
sort(test_mat)
```

I'm not entirely sure which method is right, as I'm getting quite different results from each.

Comment: `test_mat` has five elements in the first row but only four elements in the 2nd and 3rd row. This is not possible for a matrix

Comment: @Sardar Usama sorry the first row “0” at the end shouldn’t been there. I accidentally typed an extra number

Comment: @Maxxx: You can edit your question to fix that typo; that's good practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Sardar Usama's comment I'm using the test matrix:

```
A = [10 40 30 -1; 
    43 78 -5 1; 
    87 54 -4 -2];
```

`sort(A,dim)` sorts every vector of `A` in ascending order. If `dim` is 1, then every column vector, if `dim` is 2 then ever row vector.

E.g.:`sort(A, 2)`sorts every row of `A` in ascending order. This means that every row will be considered a row vector and will be sorted in ascending order.

```
% ascending sorting of every row vector
sort(A,2)
ans =
    -1    10    30    40
    -5     1    43    78
    -4    -2    54    87

% ascending sorting of every column vector
sort(A,1)
ans =
    10    40    -5    -2
    43    54    -4    -1
    87    78    30     1
```

`sortrows(A, col)` sorts the rows of `A` in ascending order according to the column `col`. The individual rows don't change, so the rows are not modified.

E.g.:`sortrows(A,1)`won't change `A` at all, since the first column is already in ascending order.

```
sortrows(A,1)
ans = 10    40    30    -1
      43    78    -5     1
      87    54    -4    -2
```

If you just use `sortrows(A)`, `A` will always be sorted according to the first column by default, if you use `sortrows(A,1)`, it does therefore the same thing, but you could also use `sortrows(A,3)` and sort according to the 3rd column. Additionally you can also use `sortrows(A,[1 3])`, which sorts first based on column 1 and all rows where column 1 has the same value will be sorted according to column 3. `sortrows(A,[1 2 3 4])` is of course the same as `sortrows(A)`. (thats the default)

So if your rows are feature vectors, `sortrows` will order your feature vectors according to one of the features/columns, but the feature vectors/rows itself will stay unchanged and `sort` will also change the rows/feature vectors itself, since every row will be changed/sorted in ascending order. So I guess you want `sortrows`.

If you only have numeric values, I don't see any reason for casting.

Comment: thank you! Is there any difference between sortrows(A) and sortrows(A,1)?

Comment: ah thank you very much. Way better explanation than matlab documentation.

Comment: "If you only have numeric values, I don't see any reason for casting." This is good advice: in Matlab, numerics are _way_ faster than strings, so you should always stick with numerics whenever you can. And the lexicographical sorting for strings is not the same as the numeric sorting for the numbers they represent, so working in the string domain will give you the wrong answer here!

Comment: @AndrewJanke thank you. because i saw from some other post few weeks back where 10,1 and 2 are being used, and the person who asked wanted to sort them lexicographically, to obtain 1 10 2. However, it was only possible if they are represented as strings, hence the confusion when i was working on matrices in matlab. This link https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/144240-how-can-i-perform-lexicographic-sorting-on-a-cell

Comment: @AndrewJanke i assume that A = [1;10;2] and A = [1 10 2], and sortrows(A) on both would still be [1;2;10] and [1 2 10] respectively but this is lexicographical order for matrices?

Comment: I believe that is correct: as I understand it, "lexicographical order" of things means ordering items based on a descending-significance order of their respective components, and as I've seen it used, "lexicographical order" for matrices considers the rows of the matrix to be "items" and columns of the matrix to be their "components", in this sense. In other words, a radix sort on the columns of the matrix. I think the Matlab Central post you're linking to is using a weird definition of "lexicographical ordering" for this context, and is not what OP is asking here.

Comment: But let's just ask OP: @Maxxx, what exactly do you mean by "lexicographical order" here?

Comment: @AndrewJanke to be honest all i know is that it is "dictionary sort", for strings it's simple but for numbers I'm not quite certain if my eyes is able to dictate if a long list of numbers for example is in lexicographical order. Since i have a matrix where each row is a feature vector, i would now assume that it's not possible to view each numbers individually to perform the sort but rather in rows like what you've said. Come to think of it, I'm starting to see that sorting a list of numbers, [10,50,1,20,3,4] is different from sorting a matrix of numbers, since matrices are 2 dimensional.

Comment: Okay, yep, you mean what I meant: sorting rows as "items", based on columns in turn; not the weird thing that Matlab Central post was talking about. This answer's right, then: you want `sortrows()`. Thanks!